# TypeORM: How to get joined columns into entity as value?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, one-to-one, relation

I try to join data of different tables `tbl_book_locations`, `tbl_book_sizes` into one entity `book` (the other tables are just for later discussions). I cannot change the database structure (sadly).

So this is my structure in the database:

[image: book example]

```js
book.entity.ts
@Entity({
  name: 'tbl_books',
  schema: 'X',
})
export class Book extends BaseItems {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'item_id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'title' })
  name: string;

  @OneToOne(() => BookLocation, (x) => x.locations, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'book_id',
    //referencedColumnName: 'geo_lat',
  })
  locations: object | null;

  geo_lat:number
  geo_lon:number

  @AfterLoad()
  setComputed() {
    //inherit from the entity
    this.geo_lat= this.locations['geo_lat'];
    this.geo_lon= this.locations['geo_lon'];
  }
```

```js
booklocation.entity.ts
@Entity({
  name: 'tbl_book_locations',
  schema: 'X',
})
export class BookLocation extends BaseItems {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'book_id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'geo_lat' })
  geo_lat: number;

  @Column({ name: 'geo_lon' })
  geo_lon: number;

  //reverse but not really "needed"
  @OneToOne(() => Book)
  locations: object | null;
```

So my problem is that the computing and all the fields like `locations` are not really handy.. I aim for a object like this at the end:

```json
{
  id: 123456,
  name: "My Book"
  geo_lat: 434.3223
  geo_lon: 23.3233
}
```

What I get currently is like:

```json
{
  id: 123456,
  name: "My Book",
  geo_lat: 434.3223,
  geo_lon: 23.3233,
  locations: {
      id: 123456,
      geo_lat: 434.3223,
      geo_lon: 23.3233,      
      }     
}
```

Is it even possible to achieve to get the joined columns of the relation back directly into the entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need joined field at entity, you can use "relations" option exclusively at find option.

sample (not tested):

```
bookRepository.findOne(1, {
  relations: {
    locations: false,
  },
});
```

And after this you can convert null to undefined if needed.

[typeorm find options doc](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options)

Comment: But I want the data of the relation.. just not in the format like it is coming in

Comment: Then how about just create a function that returns object from Book class as your need of data?

Comment: Well my thought was that when I have relationships which are using Book class that it should be properly formatted as Entity, not re-formated afterwards?

Comment: Then if you just iterate the Book entity whether Book entity contains "locations" or not doesn't matter performance that much. Because it is just reference to object from perspective of Book object.